# Remove object from NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an array with following elements in `ViewDidLoad` method

```
inputArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"car", @"bus", @"helicopter", @"cruiz", @"bike", @"jeep", nil];
```

I have another `UITextField` for searching the elements .So once i type some thing in `UITextField` i want  to check whether that string is present in "inputArray" or not.If it is not matching with elements  in inputArray then  remove the corresponding elements from inputArray .

```
 for (NSString* item in inputArray)
   {
        if ([item rangeOfString:s].location == NSNotFound) 
        {
            [inputArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:item];//--> Shows Exception
            NSLog(@"Contains :%@",containsAnother);
        }

  }
```

but this code shows exception , something related to "removeobject:"

**Exception  :**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
`
```

Comment: what exception are you getting?. It has to be mutable. But according to your question its not.

Comment: erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @Naveen If that's your exception, you should look at your arguments (probably `s`) and see which one is `nil`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
for (int i=0;i<[inputArray count]; i++) {
        NSString *item = [inputArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([item rangeOfString:s].location == NSNotFound) {
            [inputArray removeObject:item];
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This makes sense. Alternatively, you can iterate the index, _i,_ in reverse order, which saves you the effort of needing to adjust the index as you remove items. But I like this.

Comment: Also you need to mention why this way to adapt, not fast enumeraion.

Comment: If you are performing fast enumeration on an Object, you can't remove objects from it. If you try to remove objects from NSMutableArray which is being fast enumerated, it will throw an exception. That's why I have used traditional for-loop.

Answer (score 10):

In fast enumeration you can **NOT** modify the collection.

The enumerator object becomes constant and immutable.

If you want to do updation on the array

You should like this :

```
NSMutableArray *inputArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"car", @"bus", @"helicopter", @"cruiz", @"bike", @"jeep", nil];
NSString *s=@"bus";

for (int i=inputArray.count-1; i>-1; i--) {
    NSString *item = [inputArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([item rangeOfString:s].location == NSNotFound) {
        [inputArray removeObject:item];
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The above works similar as this :

```
NSArray *array=[inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@",s]];
```

Comment: item is from inputArray and s is also from inputArray???? so where i add my search text?

Comment: You should probably either break the loop in the `if` and hence guarantee that you only remove the first occurrence or count the index counter down by one, since you have removed an item and hence "dropped" the rest of the array by one. Since this may look strange in a `for` loop, you could use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: I only converted your code to conventional for loop. Rest you know better than me :)

Comment: @Monolo: I dint went into deep of the working, just found the error and converted fast-enum to convention for.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya when i search "bus " its shows result as Contains :(
    bus,
    cruiz,
    jeep
)

Comment: @Naveen: do you wnat your final result always the array contain `s` ?

Comment: @yes ,but the real problem is i have two array to search one string "s"

Comment: i dint get you. if your string `s` value is bus, what should be your answer. As in my answer I am finding getting the result as "bus"

Comment: @AnoopVaidya your code is working ,but if i have two array inputArray and inputArray1  the when i search string"bus"  i want to check in both arrays and save it into an array

Comment: @AnoopVaidya +1 on pointing out `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`. If using `NSMutableArray`, you can also directly `filterUsingPredicate`.

Comment: @Rob I like the idea of using `filterUsingPredicate:` directly - it does what the OP asks for, in one easily understandable line of code.

Comment: @Rob:Thanks :) I know without support from you all, I could n't learn and earn this much of points.

Answer (score 0):

That needs to be an `NSMutableArray`.  You can't modify an `NSArray` once created (except to start all over).

Change this:

```
inputArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"car", @"bus", @"helicopter", @"cruiz", @"bike", @"jeep", nil];
```

to this:

```
inputArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"car", @"bus", @"helicopter", @"cruiz", @"bike", @"jeep", nil];
```

and also change the property to NSMutableArray also:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *inputArray;
```

Comment: after using ur coding am getting  'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]: nil argument'

Answer (score 0):

The `s` in your question is probably nil. So your are getting the exception.Please check that out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clean solution that I like to use. You define a NSArray category to extend it and create a **map** method. This method creates a new NSArray based on what you return within your block:

```
@interface NSArray (BlockExtensions)
/*! 
 Invokes block once for each element of self, returning a new array containing the
 values returned by the block.
 */
- (NSArray *)map:(id (^)(id obj))block;

@end

@implementation NSArray (BlockExtensions)

- (NSArray *)map:(id (^)(id obj))block
{
    return [self mapWithOptions:0 usingBlock:^id(id obj, NSUInteger idx) {
        return block(obj);
    }];
} 

- (NSArray *)mapWithOptions:(NSEnumerationOptions)options usingBlock:(id (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx))block
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self count]];
    [self enumerateObjectsWithOptions:options usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)     {

        id newobj = block? block(obj, idx) : obj;
        if (newobj)
            [array addObject:newobj];
    }];
    return array;
}
    @end
```

The block will be called once for every item in your original array, passing this object as a parameter:

```
NSArray *newArray = [inputArray map:^id(NSString *item) {
    if ([item rangeOfString:s].location == NSNotFound) {
        return item;
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

`newArray` will contain your filtered out items!

Comment: And where does `mapWithOptions` come from?

Comment: Yes, sorry. There you go. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use following Code. (*This Code is use for filter Array base on input string/text of `UITextField`* )

Take Two `NSMutableArray` and **add one array to  another array** in `ViewDidLoad` method such like,

```
self.listOfTemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // array no - 1
self.ItemOfMainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"YorArrayList", nil]; // array no - 2 

[self.listOfTemArray addObjectsFromArray:self.ItemOfMainArray]; // add 2array to 1 array
```

**And Write following delegate Method of UISearchBar**

```
- (BOOL) textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
 {
        NSString *name = @"";
        NSString *firstLetter = @"";

    if (self.listOfTemArray.count > 0)
         [self.listOfTemArray removeAllObjects];

        if ([searchText length] > 0)
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < [self.ItemOfMainArray count] ; i = i+1)
                {
                        name = [self.ItemOfMainArray objectAtIndex:i];

                        if (name.length >= searchText.length)
                        {
                                firstLetter = [name substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
                                //NSLog(@"%@",firstLetter);

                                if( [firstLetter caseInsensitiveCompare:searchText] == NSOrderedSame )
                                {
                                    // strings are equal except for possibly case
                                    [self.listOfTemArray addObject: [self.ItemOfMainArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                                    NSLog(@"=========> %@",self.listOfTemArray);
                                }
                         }
                 }
         }
         else
         {
             [self.listOfTemArray addObjectsFromArray:self.ItemOfMainArray ];
         }

        [self.tblView reloadData];
}
```

}

Output Show in your `Console.`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you can't mutate an array while it is being enumerated. The easiest way to do what you want and keep the convenience of fast enumeration is to copy the array.

```
for (NSString* item in [inputArray copy]) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Note that as soon as you remove one element in `inputArray`, the indexes of `inputArray` and `[inputArray copy]` do not match anymore.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Anoop for pointing out that you can use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`. Thus, if you wanted to create a new array based upon the matches in `inputArray`, you could also use something like:

```
NSArray *matchingArray = [inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", s]];
```

Alternatively, given that `inputArray` is a `NSMutableArray` you can simply filter the array with this single line:

```
[inputArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", s]];
```

Or, if you like blocks:

```
[inputArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return ([evaluatedObject rangeOfString:s].location != NSNotFound);
}]];
```